# The requested resource does not support HTTP method GET

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When I run this url: `/api/users/1` it does only map to the Delete action when I use the HttpDelete-Attribute. What is the reason for this behavior?

Else I get his message: The requested resource does not support HTTP method GET

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public UserController(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<UserDTO>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, _userService.GetUsers());
    } 

    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpDelete]
    public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        _userService.Delete(id);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "User was deleted successfully");
    }
}
```

These are my routes:

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "ActionApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
               defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Start", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By convention, HTTP verbs will match to an action name that is prefixed with that HTTP verb.

So, it's complaining you don't have an action for an HTTP GET, which is the verb used when you make a simple request with your browser. You need an action named something like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
```

or even

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetUser(int id)
```

Obviously if you make a request with DELETE, it will map to the Delete action you have defined.

Ref: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api

"To find the action, Web API looks at the HTTP method, and then looks for an action whose name begins with that HTTP method name. For example, with a GET request, Web API looks for an action that starts with "Get...", such as "GetContact" or "GetAllContacts".  This convention applies only to GET, POST, PUT, and DELETE methods. You can enable other HTTP methods by using attributes on your controller. We’ll see an example of that later."

Comment: You see the "removed for brevity" comment there was my public HttpResponseMessage Get() so this can not be the reason you speak of. I have updated my question with the full code (Get method)

Comment: But you're missing the GET action that accepts a parameter. Based on your URL /api/users/1, you're looking to pass 1 in as an argument, but you don't have a GET action that accepts one. Routing is looking for an action like `public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)`

Comment: When I use fiddler with api/users/1 and set the http verb to DELETE then it works. But when I trigger the api/users/1 in the browser url it wants to trigger the Get(int id) (as you said). Does that mean every url firing in the browser is a GET request by default?

Comment: Then your statement:"By convention, HTTP verbs will match to an action name that is prefixed with that HTTP verb." makes sense trigger in the browser url and I need a Get(int id) technically seen OR in my case I have to attribute my Delete with HttpDelete :-) Thanks!